# timeseries model recommendation

Tags: r, time-series, survival-analysis

I'm new in time-series and I have an EHR (electronic health record) dataset.
I have sequentially measured the time-series Electronic Health Record patient dataset. This is 7 years of research and each patient's blood pressure, Hba1c, LDL, Hb, Baseline Age,...were measured (as the independent variable for modeling) every 4 months and at the same time, each patient was classified as healthy/not healthy (output/dependent variable). Before modeling, we assigned the output of each patient only as 0 /1 (0= if the patient is assigned 0 at least once, 1= otherwise). So we have time-series (HBA, fpg, ...) and not time-series measures (race, baseline_age) for independent variables , but only one output (0/1) for each patient. I want to model this data, there are some methods used for such kind of dataset, such as; using baseline values or using the mean value of each independent variable. In addition to these two methods, I want to use time-series analysis, but I am not sure what am I going to use? Looks like a survival analysis, but it is not, since the research didn't end when we see 0 value. You can see the visualization of the data structure below. Thanks for all your responses in advance.Also you can see a code of toy example of my data structure below.[image]

```
features <-data.frame( 
                     Patient = c("Patient1","Patient1","Patient1", "Patient2" ,"Patient2","Patient2","Patient3" ,"Patient3","Patient3"),
                     Time=c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3"),
                     Hba=c(8.3,8.4, 8.2, 7.1,7.3,7.2,6.9,6.8,6.5), 
                     fpg=c(98,90,92,88,89,87,100,105,108), 
                     Age=c(66,66,66,48,48,48,78,78,78))
 
response <-data.frame( Patient = c("Patient1","Patient2","Patient3"),
                       Output = c(1,0,1))
```

Comment: First plot the data in multiple ways and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: I sounds as though there is another variable representing observations over time that you are summarizing with the "response" variable.